# Lightning Component Indexing in VisualStudioCode hogs CPU and memory slowing my PC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, vs-code, indexing, cpu, slowness

I keep seeing "Indexing Lightning Components" in Visual Studio Code, which is a CPU and Memory hogging activity, slowing my PC. Is there a way to make it less CPU intensive?

[image: #VisualStudioCode #IndexingLightningComponent #CPUHog]

Comment: Try to close and reopen Visual Studio a few times. I have similar issues on IntellJ IDEA sometimes...

Comment: Same issue, any solution ? I also tried reopening...

Comment: Something is wrong - I'm getting too... I guess I should file a bug with the vscode team

Answer (score 3):

I added the same comment to Saleforce github issues for VS Code Salesforce dx plugin, and it was marked as a bug by SF team. Seems the issue is with Aura Component extension for VS Code by Salesforce. It can be checked at below link
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/1592

Comment: Disabling aura component extension removed errors and CPU drain, thank you

Comment: Disable aura component extension would be useful is one is not developing in lightning.